# Unable to Implement cosine similarity for simple k-means in JAVA for WEKA

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, weka, cosine-similarity

I am pretty new to Java's WEKA API of ML.

Since there is no cosine similarity algorithm in weka , I thought of adding this algorithm to WEKA by modifying the simpleKmeans algorithm of WEKA.

The simpleKmeans algo in weka makes use of `EuclideanDistance` and i wish to use cosine similarity instead of euclideanDistance.

I googled a lot about how to modify the WEKA open source software's code of simpleKmeans algo and found this matter on net(basically pedro's view)

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ai.weka/22681

the steps mentioned here are :

1. extend the `weka.core.EuclideanDistance` and override the distance(Instance first, 
   Instance second, PerformanceStats stats) method.
2. instantiate it as the extended class using the `EuclideanDistance` as the type, 
    passing the Instances as the parameters for the extended class  constructor.
3. use the `setDistanceFunction` method from the `SimpleKMeans` class passing the
   `EuclideanDistance` instance.

here is the code for the first part of the process for WEKA.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package weka.core;

import weka.core.Attribute;
//import weka.core.EuclideanDistance;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
import weka.core.neighboursearch.PerformanceStats;
import weka.core.TechnicalInformation.Type;

/**
 *
 * @author Sgr
 */
public class CosineSimilarity extends EuclideanDistance{

 public Instances m_Data = null;
 public String version ="1.0";

 @Override
 public double distance(Instance arg0, Instance arg1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return distance(arg0, arg1, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, null);
 }

 @Override
 public double distance(Instance arg0, Instance arg1, PerformanceStats arg2) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return distance(arg0, arg1, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, arg2);
 }

 @Override
 public double distance(Instance arg0, Instance arg1, double arg2) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return distance(arg0, arg1, arg2, null);
 }

 @Override
 public double distance(Instance first, Instance second, double cutOffValue,PerformanceStats arg3) {

    double distance = 0;
    int firstI, secondI;
    int firstNumValues = first.numValues();
    int secondNumValues = second.numValues();
    int numAttributes = m_Data.numAttributes();
    int classIndex = m_Data.classIndex();
    double normA, normB;
    normA = 0;
    normB = 0;

    for (int p1 = 0, p2 = 0; p1 < firstNumValues || p2 < secondNumValues;) {

        if (p1 >= firstNumValues)
            firstI = numAttributes;
        else firstI = first.index(p1);


        if (p2 >= secondNumValues)
            secondI = numAttributes;
        else secondI = second.index(p2);

        if (firstI == classIndex) {
            p1++;
           continue;
        }
//   if ((firstI < numAttributes)) {
//    p1++;
//    continue;
//   }

        if (secondI == classIndex) {
            p2++;
            continue;
        }
//   if ((secondI < numAttributes)) {
//    p2++;
//    continue;
//   }

        double diff;

        if (firstI == secondI) {

            diff = difference(firstI, first.valueSparse(p1), second.valueSparse(p2));
            normA += Math.pow(first.valueSparse(p1), 2);
            normB += Math.pow(second.valueSparse(p2), 2);
            p1++;
            p2++;

        } 

        else if (firstI > secondI) {

            diff = difference(secondI, 0, second.valueSparse(p2));
            normB += Math.pow(second.valueSparse(p2), 2);
            p2++;

        }

        else {
            diff = difference(firstI, first.valueSparse(p1), 0);
            normA += Math.pow(first.valueSparse(p1), 2);
            p1++;
        }

        if (arg3 != null)
            arg3.incrCoordCount();

        distance = updateDistance(distance, diff);

        if (distance > cutOffValue)
            return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        }

  //do the post here, don't depends on other functions
  //System.out.println(distance + " " + normA + " "+ normB);
        distance = distance/Math.sqrt(normA)/Math.sqrt(normB);
        distance = 1-distance;

        if(distance < 0 || distance > 1)
            System.err.println("unknown: " + distance);

        return distance;

    }

 public double updateDistance(double currDist, double diff){

     double result;
    result = currDist;
    result += diff;

    return result;
 }

 public double difference(int index, double val1, double val2){

     switch(m_Data.attribute(index).type()){

         case Attribute.NOMINAL:
                            return Double.NaN;
                            //break;
         case Attribute.NUMERIC:
                              return val1 * val2;
                            //break;
    }

     return Double.NaN;
 }

 @Override
 public String getAttributeIndices() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public Instances getInstances() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return m_Data;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean getInvertSelection() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public void postProcessDistances(double[] arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void setAttributeIndices(String arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void setInstances(Instances arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  m_Data = arg0;
 }

 @Override
 public void setInvertSelection(boolean arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub


  //do nothing
 }

 @Override
 public void update(Instance arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  //do nothing
 }

 @Override
 public String[] getOptions() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public Enumeration listOptions() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public void setOptions(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public String getRevision() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return "Cosine Distance function writtern by Sgr, version " + version;
 }


}
```

But i am not able to process the next two steps as I am not very well versed with weka.

I saw the source code of simpleKmeans in weka and observed that it creates an instance of `EuclideanDistance` class but i am clueless regarding the further procedure.

Kindly help me regarding the next 2 steps to be carried out. If there is a mistake in this implementation of cosine similarity, kindly figure it out. Also, if anyone can modify the code of SimpleKmeans in weka for my cosine implementation or explain me the places where I should make changes in that code, it would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Weka is really *weak* when it comes to clustering. It also is rather slow.

Have you had a look at [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/). It has much more choices when it comes to clustering and outlier detection than Weka. You can experiment with cosine similarity in k-means out-of-the-box in ELKI.

However, note that **k-means is not distance-based**. It is minimizing variances (sum-of-squares), and **k-means may stop converging if you use other distance functions**. The reason is **the mean is a L2-optimal center**, but it does *not* optimize other distance functions. It's only optimizing the sum-of-squares, which is the same as *squared Euclidean distance*.

Often, k-means with other distances (such as Cosine) *may* work and converge for *your* data set. But the **convergence proofs require sum-of-squares**. In fact, using k-means with cosine similarity may also yield a division-by-0 error, when the mean of a cluster becomes 0 (even when your data did not contain a zero vector).

There are a number of variations, such as k-medoids, that *do* support other distance functions. They should also be available in ELKI, as far as I remember.

Comment: `@Anony-Mousse` thanku sir!! but I wish to have a `distance function` in weka that uses cosine similarity. I was able to add my `cosinesimilarity` algorithm in `weka.core` package. But I am not able to correctly execute the `2nd and 3rd step` (the ones i mentioned in my question). It would be extremely useful if you can help me out to achieve that. My main aim is to `add cosinesimilarity in simplekmeans` algo in weka.

Comment: I don't use Weka anymore. It's too slow. For clustering, ELKI is much better; and for classification I use scikit-learn. `CosineSimilarity extends EuclideanDistance` sounds like a dangerous abuse of OOP inheritance... Cosine is *not* a subtype of Euclidean distance.

Comment: Nevertheless, **k-means should not use distances at all** IMHO. The fastest k-means implementations do actually *not* compute any distance - they directly optimize the target function `sum |x_ki - c_ji|^2`, which only "looks like" squared Euclidean distance.

Comment: Either way, try using ELKI. You need to write **0** lines of code, because it already includes all you need. You can configure k-means to run with cosine similarity in ELKI (but it will warn that this might not converge).